# how to draw images from another class in android?

Tags: java, android, image

I am new to android graphics as far as custom views and such. I have the following program, but the SurfaceView for some reason will not draw a image from an object of another class. I continue to get a null pointer exception.

MAIN CLASS:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

MyView view;
TestObject test;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view = new MyView(this, this);
    test = new TestObject(this);
    setContentView(view);
}

public TestObject getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(TestObject test) {
    this.test = test;
}

}
```

VIEW CLASS:

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {


SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
Thread thread;
TestObject test;

public MyView(Context context, Main main) {
    super(context);
    this.test = main.getTest();
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        if(!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(test.getImage(), test.getX(), test.getY(), null);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

}
```

OBJECT CLASS:

```
public class TestObject {

Main main;
Bitmap image;
int x,y;
DisplayMetrics dm;

public TestObject(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(main.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    x = dm.widthPixels / 2;
    y = dm.heightPixels / 2;
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}   

}
```

I get a null pointer exception at `canvas.drawBitmap(test.getImage(), test.getX(), test.getY(), null);` in the MyView class. Strangly, it will work if if was to say `canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(main.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), 0, 0, null);` (or any other x, y position).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I see you create test after the view, so it is null. Change the creation order of test and view. `view = new MyView(this, this);` and `test = new TestObject(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You should override "onDraw" method of "MyView" instead of implementing Runnable.